# Is it possible to develop this iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm a beginner of iOS app development,
I'm working on a very small project to show useful info of another app
i simply want it to check the out/ingoing packets through my device and find a specific packet where its string contains a specific word, if found then show the whole packet content,

is it possible to be done and does apple allow tracking packets ? thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437061/how-do-you-monitor-network-traffic-on-the-iphone

Comment: It sound likes a sniffer. Maybe it can be done with libpcap, but you need the root to access related device:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071034/can-libpcap-be-compiled-for-iphone-armv6

Comment: yes i already seen the packet itself but i want to do this process on a separated app, device is already jailbr0ken, i have the root access, wireshark shows loads of packets and complex method to see them that also needs processes to be done before sniffering packets so i think tweak/app is a good solution

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3ruWy4dLJ4
Best tutorial for beginners

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of it being possible or not (I'm guessing the answer is no, since you probably need root access and more low level APIs that aren't available by default), you want to track other applications. More specifically the network activity of these applications. This imposes several 'difficulties';

- Given their policies, Apple will not allow this.
- Your application will need to be active on the foreground, while background activity of applications is limited. The number of packets you will be able to 'sniff' will be very minimal and if you chose to put your application in the background instead your time will be limited to about 10 minutes of execution time.

My advice? Don't. Unless you are interested in the jailbreak 'market'.

Comment: I dont know about its jailbreak requirement but I'm sure you can keep your application live in background-just register your application as Navigator app or voip application.so that you can sniff packets continuously.