# tcpdump implementation/adaptation

Tags: ipad, wrapper, packet-capture, tcpdump

I want to make an iPad app that
analyze the data traffic using: "tcpdump" 
The app should be somehow a implementation/adaptation/wrapper 
the/for the "tcpdump" command.

I zapped through the http://www.tcpdump.org/, 
but I want to save time, 
so I want ask you for some guidelines in order to solve this.

1. Is there any wrapper "libpcap" library for objective-c?
   Or any other API that handles the "tcpdump" command in iOS.
2. How do I use a C/C++ library in an iPhone/iPad app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I didn't find an Obj-C wrapper for pcap either.  Not surprising considering some points raised [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6825707/143136).  @Guy Harris points out the problem specifically: unless you're running on a jailbroken device, you're going to be lacking the permissions to read the data.
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3779801/143136) (specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3779873/143136)) suggests that you just properly name the files, then compile and link

Good luck.

Comment: In particular, note that the answer mentioned in point 1 says that, unless you are doing this on a jailbroken iPad, you will not be able to give tcpdump (or any other app) sufficient privileges to open a BPF device and thus will not be able to give it sufficient privileges to capture traffic.

Comment: Thanks again for these observations.